# Importing systemverilog package as another name

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Is there a mechanism to import a systemverilog package as another name, similar to what is available in Python?

I have a package I need to import, and the name of the package is `top_pkg`. I want to import it as `subsystem_pkg`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a a mechanism, but it is not easy for this purpose. What you can do is create a `subsystem_pkg` that imports `top_pkg`. Then you can `export` all the symbols imported from `top_pkg` so they will appear as if they were directly declared inside `subsystem_pkg` Normally, only those symbols declared inside a package are what are available to import, not what the package has imported (sometimes called a chaining of imports). The `export` command chains the imports.

What makes this difficult for this purpose is the way wildcarding works for import and exports. Every symbol you want chained has to explicitly appear in the chaining package. For example

```
package top_pkg;
  int a,b,c,d;
endpackage
package subsystem;
  import top_pkg::*;
  import top_pkg::b;
  export top_pkg::*;
  export top_pkg::c;
  int e = d;
endpackage
```

The first `import` statement say make all symbols in top_pkg *candidates* for importation; it doesn't actually import anything.  The second import statement explicitly imports `b`. The first `export` statement says to export any symbol that was imported from `top_pkg`, which at this point is only `b`. The second `export` statement implicitly imports, then explicitly exports `c`. The last statement causes an implicit import of `d`, as well as an implicit export 'd'.

So when you import `subsystem_pkg`, you get symbols b,c and d from `top_pkg` as well as the locally declared `e.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I decided to use a seperate package file that included the files I need specifically

Comment: That would work as long as no one imports both packages and there is no communication between the two packages. See http://go.mentor.com/package-import-versus-include